# Check if object already exists in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I`m fairly new to Java and I´m trying to make a simple program where you add events to an ArrayList. Now I´m trying to make a function that checks if the event typed in by the user already exists in the Arraylist. If it does, I want the program to print a message, exit the method and return to the start menu. Any suggestions? This is my code for this so far:

```
    public void addEvent() {

    System.out.println("Event name: ");
    String eventName = norm();

    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.size(); i++) {

        if (allEvents.get(i).getEventName().equalsIgnoreCase(eventName)) 
        System.out.println(eventName + " has already been added! ");

        **// Break out of method and return to menu**
    }

    System.out.println("Attempts allowed: ");
    int noOfAttempts = readInt();
    while (noOfAttempts < 1) {
        System.out.println("To low, must allow at least 1 attempt. Try again: ");
        noOfAttempts = readInt();
    }
    allEvents.add(new Event(eventName, noOfAttempts));
    System.out.println(eventName + " added \n");

    }
```

Comment: *Any suggestions?* about what? What is your concrete question? What do you expect this code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Sorry for being ambigious. So far the code searches my ArrayList for the user input, and my question really is how I should write the the code to exit the method if a match is found, instead of it continuing to "System.out.println("Attempts allowed: ");"

Comment: add `return;` inside your `if`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but then it says my i++ contains dead code for some reason?

Comment: Probably because you didn't put the return inside the if, but outside. **Always** use braces for if, for, while, etc.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Thanks for the help!